# PhoneGap plugin push doesn't work with iOS

Tags: cordova, push-notification, phonegap, cordova-plugin-fcm

Looked at other questions, no one seems to have specific problems related to installing the phonegap-push-plugin.

I have been trying to sort this one out for a while.

I'm only on Windows and have been relying on phonegap-build to do iOS builds.

For some reason the JavaScript portion of iOS related to the plugin is failing.

I looked in weinre, and the console is empty.

I also tried to catch and display errors in the JavaScript, but for some reason `PushNotification` errors aren't showing up.

Here's the JavaScript.

I call it with a button after the app loads:

```
alert("REGISTER");
alert(""+PushNotification);
var push = PushNotification.init({
     "android": {"senderID": "661780372179"} 
});
alert(""+push);
push.on('registration', function(data) {
  console.log(data.registrationId);
  console.log(data.registrationType);
});
```

If I just have the plugin installed, I'll get the messages:

REGISTER, then Undefined.
I tried including the push.js from the push plugin example, in which case it does:

REGISTER, then [entire text of the PushNotification]

ios version is 9.3.5. I'm using a non-distribution key.

It has never gotten past PushNotification.init

It works fine in Android.

I've also tried: phonegap create my-app --template phonegap-template-push
and looked through their code, can't tell what is different.

How can I catch all such errors and print them (window.onerror doesn't work I have no idea why)

Why is PushNotification undefined? I thought phonegap would automatically inject it. In the docs it says to use cocoapods do I need that? Here's the requirements https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/docs/INSTALLATION.md

How do I properly include phonegap-plugin-push?

Here are my plugins:

```
cordova-plugin-compat 1.2.0 "Compat"
cordova-plugin-console 1.1.0 "Console"
cordova-plugin-contacts 2.3.1 "Contacts"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.7 "Device"
cordova-plugin-dialogs 1.3.4 "Notification"
cordova-plugin-file 4.3.3 "File"
cordova-plugin-firebase-messaging 0.13.0 "FirebaseMessagingPlugin"
cordova-plugin-globalization 1.11.0 "Globalization"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 1.7.2 "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 3.2.2 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.4.2 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.3 "Whitelist"
cordova-support-google-services 1.1.0 "cordova-support-google-services"
phonegap-plugin-multidex 1.0.0 "Multidex"
phonegap-plugin-push 2.2.3 "PushPlugin"
```